# How to use jquery validation errorplacement for only one error field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, errorplacement

I am using jQuery validation to validate a form. My form is slit up into sections. The top part of the form, which has normal inputs, the validation error messages are being placed exactly as I want them.

My issue is that a specific error label that is placed in a different section will not display. I was told to try our the `errorplacement` function, but I do not see how I can use this with one specific error message.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

}
```

In my code below, you will see two `HTML` comments. The first one is to illustrate that if I move the input there, then the error message will display. The second comment is where the input is currently and where I actually want it, but it will not display there.

The input's id is `#interestHidden`.

Does anyone see how I can use `errorplacement` for just this one error message?

See my code below

```
<section class="sec90">
            <h3 class="subTC">Enter your information below.</h3>
            <form action="" id="salesforce_submit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div><input id="first_name" placeholder="First Name*" class="input block" maxlength="40" name="first_name" type="text"></div>
                <div><input id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name*" class="input block" maxlength="80" name="last_name" type="text"></div>
                <div><input id="company" placeholder="Company*" class="input block" maxlength="40" name="company" type="text"></div>
                <!-- Moving it here will allow the message to display -->
        </section>
        <section class="sec90">
                <h3 class="subTC">What are you interested in?*</h3>
<!-- Moving it here, it doesn't show -->
                <div><input type="hidden" id="interestHidden" name="interestHidden" value=""></div>
                <div id="interestWrap">
                    <div class="interest">
```

Attempt:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.attr("id") == "interestHidden") {
                error.html('#interestError');
            } else {
                //Placement for other interest Hidden
            }
        },
```

Updated JS:

```
$('#salesforce_submit').validate({
        ignore: [],
        //ignore: "",
        rules: {
            first_name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            last_name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                //digits: true,
                minlength: 10,
                alphanumeric: true
            },
            zip: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            company: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            interestHidden: {
                required: true,
                min: 1
            }
        },
        messages: {
            first_name: {
                required: "Please enter your first name",
                minlength: "Your first name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
            },
            last_name: {
                required: "Please enter your last name",
                minlength: "Your last name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number",
                digits: "Please enter a valid phone number with only numbers",
                minlength: "Your number seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
            },
            zip: {
                required: "Please enter your zip code",
                digits: "Please enter a valid zip code with only numbers",
                minlength: "Your zip code seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
            },
            company: {
                required: "Please enter your company name",
                minlength: "Your company name seems a bit short. Please enter at least 2 characters"
            },
            interestHidden: {
                required: "Please choose at least one interest",
                min: "At least one interest needs chosen"
            }
        },
        /*errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.attr("id") == "interestHidden") {
                error.html('#interestError');
            } else {
                //Placement for other interest Hidden
            }
        },*/
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if ($(element).attr('name') == 'interestHidden') {
               // error.insertAfter($(element).next());
               error.insertBefore(element.prev('#interestHidden'));
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element); // <- default
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
```

Comment: You are not using `.html()` correctly.  Refer to the jQuery documentation.  The `.html()` method is for inserting HTML into a container.  You are attempting to insert an `ID` into the `error` element... makes no sense.

Comment: Try `error.insertBefore(element)` or if it needs to be outside of the `div`, try `error.insertBefore(element.prev('div'))`

Comment: @Sparky Thanks for the continued help. I just tried what you recommended and looked at the source you listed as the duplicate. I tried your solution and the one you gave in the other question. Neither options are working. I updated my question with my Js.

Comment: I recommend you study "jQuery traversal" techniques. `element.prev('#interestHidden')`does not make sense. The element itself IS  `'#interestHidden'`, so you cannot get to the previous `'#interestHidden'` - it does not exist. In other words, you are asking for the `'#interestHidden'` that comes immediately preceding `'#interestHidden'`. Refer to the docs at jQuery website.

Comment: Since it's inside the `div`, you need to use `.parent()`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/5hrxp0v4

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion, but it still isn't working. I put `console.log` statements in the if/else statement and the else always runs, despite what is selected. I put a demo together to show you what it is doing. https://jsfiddle.net/1Ltkq7wy/12/

Comment: **Broken HTML!**  Your opening `<form>` tag was nested inside the first `<section></section>` container.  Pay attention to the errors in jsFiddle;  that one was actually flagged in red in the editor.  Also run your markup through some kind of W3C validation to make sure.  https://jsfiddle.net/1Ltkq7wy/17/

Comment: You don't need all that `checkval` junk either.  Whatever you think it's doing, should be already built into the plugin.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks again! It finally works. I had no idea that the form tag couldn't be placed like that. Regarding the `checkVal` code, that is for another use. I appreciate all of the help.

Comment: HTML structure is very important!  You cannot jumble or interweave container tags.  As you can see, broken HTML breaks other things and wastes a lot of time.  Seriously, always use the W3C markup validator.